# HTML 5 canvas drag and drop upon multiple objects

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a custom code to create and render objects on HTML5 canvas.

```js
class Rectangle extends Shape {

  constructor(options, canvas, type = 'rectangle') {
    super(...); // derived from super class

    this._options = options;
    this._canvas = canvas;
    this._context = canvas.context2D;
    this._type = type;

    this._hovered = false;
    this._dragged = false;

    this.init();

    this.canvas.canvas.onmousemove = (e) => {
      this.onMouseHover(e);
    };

    this.canvas.canvas.onmousedown = (e) => {
      this.onMouseDrag(e);
      console.log('dragging');
    }

    this.canvas.canvas.onmouseup = (e) => {
      this.onMouseRelease(e);
      console.log('release');
    }
  }

  static draw(options, canvas) {
    return new Rectangle(options, canvas);
  }

  // Getter and setter


  init() {
    this.drawRectangle(...);
  }

  onMouseHover(e) {
    if( // mouse is above of the shape position 
      e.clientX >= this.x &&
      e.clientX <= this.x + this.width &&
      e.clientY >= this.y &&
      e.clientY <= this.y + this.height
    ) {
      this.drawRectangle(...) // inverse the border color with background
      this.canvas.canvas.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    } else {
      this.drawRectangle(...) // revert to original
      this.canvas.canvas.style.cursor = 'default';
    }
  }

  onMouseDrag(e) {
    if( // mouse is above of the shape position
      e.clientX >= this.x &&
      e.clientX <= this.x + this.width &&
      e.clientY >= this.y &&
      e.clientY <= this.y + this.height &&
      !this.isDragged
    ) {

      this.canvas.canvas.onmousemove = (drag) => {  // while dragging
        this.eraseRectangle(...); // erase the rectangle

        this.drawRectangle(...); // re-draw the rectangle while dragging

        this.x = drag.clientX; // set the new x-axis value
        this.y = drag.clientY; // set the new y-axis value
      }
      this.isDragged = true;
    }
  }

  onMouseRelease(e) {
    if(this.isDragged) {
      this.isDragged = false;
      this.canvas.canvas.onmousemove = (e) => { // reset it to the original
        this.onMouseHover(e);
      }
    }
  }

  drawRectangle(width, height, x, y, fillStyle, strokeStyle) {
    this.context.beginPath();
    this.context.fillStyle = fillStyle;
    this.context.strokeStyle = strokeStyle;
    this.context.rect(x, y, width, height);
    this.context.fill();
    this.context.stroke();
  }

  eraseRectangle(width, height, x, y) {
    this.context.beginPath();
    this.context.clearRect(x-1, y-1, width+2, height+2);
  }
}
```

In the main class.

```js
class Main {

  static ready() {

    // Basic canvas options
    const options = {
      width: window.innerWidth,
      height: window.innerHeight,
      background: 'black'
    }

    // Create the canvas object
    const canvas = HTMLCanvas.build('workspace', options);
    const context = canvas.context2D;

    const rect1 = Rectangle.draw({
      width: 200,
      height: 100,
      x: 100,
      y: 200,
      border: 'blue',
      background: 'white',
      label: 'rect1'
    }, canvas);

    const rect2 = Rectangle.draw({
      width: 300,
      height: 75,
      x: 200,
      y: 400,
      border: 'green',
      background: 'white',
      label: 'rect2'
    }, canvas);
  }
 }

// Initialize the object
Main.ready();
```

With the code above, I was able to render a rectangle shape on the canvas. However, the problem is that I was not able to drag the object `rect1` anymore once the object `rect2` had been dragged.

`rect1` loses its references

I cannot drag nor hover the `rect1` object but I can still hover and drag/release the `rect2` object. Furthermore, when `rect2` is dragged over the `rect1`, `rect2` erases the `rect1`.

Example output

How we can track mouse events for each HTML5 canvas object? Most solutions would end up to iterate all of the objects (which will be drawn in the canvas) and bind the mouse event to it. I want it to be within the object itself, not within a factory class.

Comment: The simple solution to your mouse input problem is to have a handler for the context itself which will manually invoke one of your rectangle's handlers should the mouse be intersecting it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
   body {
    background-color: black;
   }
   
   canvas {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    border: solid 1px white;
    border-radius: 10px;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  <script type="application/javascript">
   
   var imageWidth = 180;
   var imageHeight = 160;
   var canvas = null;
   var ctx = null;
   var bounds = null;
   var selectedBox = null;
   var panX = 0;
   var panY = 0;
   var mouseX = 0;
   var mouseY = 0;
   var oldMouseX = 0;
   var oldMouseY = 0;
   var mouseHeld = false;
   var boxArray = [];
   
   function DraggableBox(x,y,width,height,text) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.text = text;
    this.isSelected = false;
   }
   
   DraggableBox.prototype.isCollidingWidthPoint = function(x,y) {
    return (x > this.x && x < this.x + this.width)
     && (y > this.y && y < this.y + this.height);
   }
   
   DraggableBox.prototype.drag = function(newX,newY) {
    this.x = newX - this.width * 0.5;
    this.y = newY - this.height * 0.5;
   }
   
   DraggableBox.prototype.draw = function() {
    if (this.isSelected) {
     ctx.fillStyle = "darkcyan";
     ctx.fillRect(
      this.x - panX,
      this.y - panY,
      this.width,
      this.height
     );
     ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    } else {   
     ctx.fillRect(
      this.x - panX,
      this.y - panY,
      this.width,
      this.height
     );
    }
    
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.fillText(
     this.text,
     this.x + this.width * 0.5 - panX,
     this.y + this.height * 0.5 - panY,
     this.width
    );
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
   }
   
   window.onmousedown = function(e) {
    mouseHeld = true;
   
    if (!selectedBox) {
     for (var i = boxArray.length - 1; i > -1; --i) {
      if (boxArray[i].isCollidingWidthPoint(mouseX + panX,mouseY + panY)) {
       selectedBox = boxArray[i];
       selectedBox.isSelected = true;
       requestAnimationFrame(draw);
       return;
      }
     }
    }
   }
   
   window.onmousemove = function(e) {
    mouseX = e.clientX - bounds.left;
    mouseY = e.clientY - bounds.top;
    
    if (mouseHeld) {
     if (!selectedBox) {
      panX += oldMouseX - mouseX;
      panY += oldMouseY - mouseY;
     } else {
      selectedBox.x = mouseX - selectedBox.width * 0.5 + panX;
      selectedBox.y = mouseY - selectedBox.height * 0.5 + panY;
     }
    }
    
    oldMouseX = mouseX;
    oldMouseY = mouseY;
    
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
   }
   
   window.onmouseup = function(e) {
    mouseHeld = false;
    
    if (selectedBox) {
     selectedBox.isSelected = false;
     selectedBox = null;
     requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    }
   }
   
   function draw() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "gray";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,imageWidth,imageHeight);
    
    var box = null;
    var xMin = 0;
    var xMax = 0;
    var yMin = 0;
    var yMax = 0;
    
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    
    for (var i = 0; i < boxArray.length; ++i) {
     box = boxArray[i];
     
     xMin = box.x - panX;
     xMax = box.x + box.width - panX;
     yMin = box.y - panY;
     yMax = box.y + box.height - panY;
     
     if (xMax > 0 && xMin < imageWidth && yMax > 0 && yMin < imageHeight) {
      box.draw();
     }
    }
   }
   
   window.onload = function() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    canvas.width = imageWidth;
    canvas.height = imageHeight;
    
    bounds = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.font = "15px Arial"
    
    boxArray.push(new DraggableBox(Math.random() * 320,Math.random() * 240,100,25,"This is a draggable text box"));
    boxArray.push(new DraggableBox(Math.random() * 320,Math.random() * 240,100,50,"Another text box"));
    boxArray.push(new DraggableBox(Math.random() * 320,Math.random() * 240,100,50,"Text in a box"));
    boxArray.push(new DraggableBox(Math.random() * 320,Math.random() * 240,100,50,"I find this box quite texing"));
    boxArray.push(new DraggableBox(Math.random() * 320,Math.random() * 240,150,50,"You weren't supposed to find this box"));
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
   }
   
   window.onunload = function() {
    canvas = null;
    ctx = null;
    bounds = null;
    selectedBox = null;
    boxArray = null;
   }
   
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you include some explanation? It's very hard to understand what have you done when you post only code.

Comment: Actually your code doesn't lose the reference to the canvas, whats happening is that you're overwriting the event handlers for the canvas.

Comment: Instead of this.canvas.onmouse<    >, use this.canvas.addEventListener("move",function(e) {} ); This lets you have multiple event handlers for the same event.